Ngrok not forwarding POST request data but showing in logs
The trigger for the api endpoint/webhook is a POST request which sends some data in request object. When I visit http://localhost:4040 to inspect the logs of the original request, I can see the data required by my local application. But maybe ngrok modifies the original request object and doesn't forward the original POST data to my application. Any solutions to this?
Im have also tried both ways
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))text
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
nothing seems to work
I was expecting how to solve this

Please How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

have you logged the request body? if so have seen any request body or it you just recieves empty object?
